# Spytechphone - iPhone

Tags: ports, network-scanners, iphone

When port scanning my iPhone I get an RST, ACK from 'Spytechphone' over port 8192, does anyone know what this port does?  I can't find any useful information.

[1] http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=spytechphone

Comment: Is this a work phone or your own personal phone? From my cursory google searches it seems like it is some kind of remote management software from these [people](http://www.spytech-web.com/help.shtml).

Comment: The name of the registrant may be unrelated here. I'm not an iOS user, but isn't there a netstat app in the store you can use to dump the listeners to get some more information?

Answer (score 3):

Port 8192 is one of many ports that is used for TCP/UDP. After a little bit of searching it appears that this is a port that, like #INV3NT3D said in his comment, is used by SpyTech Phone Service, among a few others.

I think a better question you need to be asking is:

"This seems like unusual traffic on my phone. Who is SpyTech Phone Service and why are they accessing my phone?"

Comment: There is no evidence that SpyTech Phone Service is "accessing the phone", only that the port is responding to scans...